# Contact Form 7 Submit not working after field error fix

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, contact-form

In my contact form 7, submit button won't work even after fixing the error, for example, if my form has *The field is required* error and if I fixed this error, contact form 7 won't detect it and I have to refresh the page to resubmit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Disable other plugins. You may have a conflict and test on a different theme.

Comment: Thanks, it was conflicting with the theme.